# Edit a WordPress site without the username and password?

Tags: wp-admin, login

I am trying to edit a website for a client who had the website built for them a few years ago. They've given me access their website server, and I can see the website is using WordPress from the folder structure.
I tried adding /wp-admin to the website, however I am getting a "Page not found" error. 
Is there a way for me to edit the WordPress site without being able to access the WordPress admin login page? I do have access to the server in which the site is stored on. 
Or could I reset the WordPress login credentials somehow, and find where the login screen is?

Comment: if it is wordpress then it might use one of the stupid "hide my wordpress" plugins. Not sure there is anyway to help without looking at all the relevant files.

Comment: renaming your /wp-content/plugins/ to /wp-content/plugins-off/ temporarily will show you if it is a plugin doing this. but try `wp-login.php` first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can check installed wordpress (wp-content).

Your login screen is here: http://example.com/folder/wp-login.php

If you have database access. You can update password (MD5) in database.

Or if you have not access. You can try code in `functions.php` only one time.

```
<?php
$user_id = 1;
$password = 'HelloWorld';
wp_set_password( $password, $user_id );
?>
```

Comment: you can put this same code in a PHP file in /wp-content/mu-plugins/ too.