# Password reset link becomes invalid immediately

Tags: wp-admin, password

I'm having an issue I've not yet come across with WordPress. 
Upon trying to reset the password, I get the validation email but when clicking it, I get the following error:

> Your password reset link appears to be invalid. Please request a new link below.

I've tried this a few times now, but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Are you using some Caching plugin?

Comment: Hi Denis, thanks for the fast reply. I initially thougth it would be cloudflare but ive disabled this.... and still no joy. No other caching though

Comment: Did you try turning all your Plugins off and switching to a default theme?

Comment: I Cannot log in to do this, its the admin pass im trying to reset

Comment: You can reset password .Please check URL.
[link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/217466/edit-a-wordpress-site-without-the-username-and-password/217468#217468)

Comment: Do you have access to phpMyAdmin? You can reset your password directly from there.

Comment: @fischi You can't possibly be serious? How are you reasonably supposed to do this with a production site?

Comment: @Craig I am absolutely serious. But I never mentioned doing stuff like this on a production site - this is why we have DTAP. How else are you going to figure out the root of the problem?

Comment: In my experience DTAP is quite uncommon in the WordPress world and the nature of WordPress itself fights against it since in most cases 95% of the system ends up being blobbed settings in the wp_options table in the database, and getting WordPress "devs" to do things any other way is like herding cats.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable caching plugin by delete or rename the plugin folder. If it doesn't work then you can try access the database via phpMyAdmin, then go to users table and click edit.

Input a new password to password field and choose function as MD5 and save.

[image]